# How to access component class variables inside a callback function in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom-events

In my component I have subscribed to html click event using `addEventListener` passed the callback function. Inside  the call back function I used a component variable like this `this.someVariable` , but I saw the scope of this has been changed and set to the html element object. Here how can I use component variables? Below I have given a sample code. Here inside my `handleHtmlClickEvent()` function I can't access the `this.x` variable.

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
   x = 'Hello';
   constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef){}
   ngOnInit(){
   }
   ngAfterViewInit(){
     const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getByElementId('123');
     element.addEventListener('click', this.handleHtmlClickEvent)
   }
   handleHtmlClickEvent(){
     console.log(this.x);
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this angular 2 ? (with TypeScript).
If Yes, there are nicer ways of doing this

Comment: It's angular 7. Can you explain the way please @SupunDeSilva ?

Comment: Sorry I am missed the message, i would take @ionut-t 's approach

Check the link out
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uj1ete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign scope to your click event

```
element.addEventListener('click', this.handleHtmlClickEvent.bind(this))
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not touch the DOM directly. It's a bad practice to do it like that.

Use `ViewChild` decorator or create a directive.

**Solution 1 - ViewChild**

In your html template assign a template variable to the element that you want to target:

```
<div #element></div>
```

In your component:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
   x = 'Hello';
   @ViewChild('element') element: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

   // use @HostListener decorator to attach your listener
   @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
   onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (event.target === this.element.nativeElement) {
      console.log(this.x);
    }
  }
}
```

**Solution 2 - Directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSomeDirective]'
})
export class SomeDirective {
   // use the Input decorator to display the message
   @Input() message: string;

   constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef){}

   @HostListener('click', ["$event"])
   onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
     console.log(this.message);
  }
}
```

In your component template:

```
<div appSomeDirective [message]="x"></div>
```

If you want to manipulate the element or elements use the [Render2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) service.

**Update**

For the case described in your comment you can do something like below:

```
 x = 'Hello';
 @ViewChild('element') element: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

 constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    const links = this.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a');

    links.forEach(link =>
      // use the Renderer2 service to start an event listener 
      this.renderer.listen(link, 'click', (event: MouseEvent) => {
        console.log(this.x);
        ...
      })
    );
  }
```

While the implementation above will work, I'm not sure how performant it will be if you have dozens or hundreds of links.

Comment: Actually  my html data is coming through api as a string and i am rendering the html using ```innerHtml``` in the div. Here is the point that, i want to catch the ```<a>``` tag click event. So what i do is, take all the ```<a>``` tag using ```this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a')``` and then added eventListener in all the ```<a>``` element. In this case how can i handle this using ```ViewChild``` ?

Comment: Thank you @ionut-t for such  help. But the problem is when i am passing the callback function as a parameter without using anonymous function the scope changed and i can't access the ```this.x``` as i mentioned in question.

Comment: @Shakibuz_Zaman I've lost track of that, but you can easily do it like V_R suggested in his answer:  `links.forEach(link => this.renderer.listen(link, 'click', this.handleHtmlClickEvent.bind(this)));`

Comment: Yes i noticed that. Btw thank you again for your help. So i am marking @V_R as accepted answer as he give solid answer first.  I wished you to mark your answer accepted but stackoverflow doesn't allow to make 2 answer as accepted :P

Comment: You're welcome and don't worry about that. It's the right way to do. Happy coding!